# FAN: Filled vs. Impressions has large gap?

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

I'm using native interstitials only (on iOS and Android), via AdMob mediation (Google Ads SDK).

I see 3 columns here for `requests`, `filled`, and `impressions`.

For whatever reason though `impressions` is always about 1/3 of `filled`.

Note: I'm not using banners or native ads, interstitials only.

I could understand this if this were on the web, with visibility and whatnot, but I'm wondering why this is happening in my native app. Does that mean the ad didn't finish downloading?

What is the proper procedure to increase my `impressions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ad impression is counted base on its visibility and also how long it stays in visibility, which different ad network has different definition.

Like other ad networks, Facebook Audience Network also requires a minimum time an ad stays in visibility before it can be counted for impression.

In your case, if users click off the interstitial ads before they meet minimum time for visibility, then the impressions will not be counted. You will see filled ads number is greater than impression number.